# How can I alert a text on input change? (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I have a function which should start, when I change the value of my input field:

```
 $('#count').change(function() {
     alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
 }).change()


<input id="count" type="number"/>
```

But what happens now is, that when I load the page the alert box appears. But it should only appear when I change the input value. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Remove `.change()` function call after binding event

Comment: i'll just add dont forget `;` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error in your HTML :

```
<input id="count" type="number">
```

And you have to apply your jQuery code at document ready :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#count').change(function () {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
  });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zlen/5rc6x42d/)

Comment: @Jarla, delighted to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

try this line

```
 $('#count').keyup(function () {
                        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
                    });
```

and your **HTML** part should be

`<input id="count" type="number"/>`

let me know if it is helpful

Comment: Nothing to add only remove

Comment: Ok no issues.. If my answer works for you, you can give the upvote so that  someone in the future can be benifited

Answer (score 0):

Remove .change() at the end

```
$('#count').change(function () {
                    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
                });
```

edit your html too

```
<input id="count" type="number"/>
```

Comment: I removed `change()`, this was almost fine, I needed also `$(document).ready(function ()` to solve the problem like Zl3n suggested

Comment: i was assuming you already had it because you did not provided complete script code